# Decorator to close open files

Tags: python

I would like to write a decorator that closes all open files. For example:

```
@close_files
def view(request):
    f = open('myfile.txt').read()
    return render('template.html')
```

Ignoring any threadsafe stuff, how could I write such a decorator to close out any open files after the function is returned? I'm not interested in writing a context manager, but something like this:

```
def close_files(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper_close_files(*args):
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # close open files here?
        return return_value
    return wrapper_close_files
```

Unfortunately I cannot use something like this:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as _f: f = _f.read()
```

I'm asking about how to do a decorator to close files where we do not have direct access to the variable which references the file (handler).

Comment: Why? I'm immediately thrown off by your rejection of a context manager, and I see you're also using Flask in your last question. What problem are you actually trying to address?

Comment: @roganjosh -- of course. I'm just curious how this would be done. In the code I'm actually using a context manager.

Comment: Mmm. I suspect that it's possible but it's probably abominable code that needs to check for file handlers in the global scope ("... that closes all open files."). I can't say that I understand the motivation but perhaps your curiosity will lead to some insights. I'm not a downvoter but I really struggle to understand the impetus

Answer (score 0):

According to python docs 3.6:
If you’re not using the with keyword, then you should call f.close() to close the file and immediately free up any system resources used by it. If you don’t explicitly close a file, Python’s garbage collector will eventually destroy the object and close the open file for you, but the file may stay open for a while. Another risk is that different Python implementations will do this clean-up at different times.

So if you want to do this, you need a decorator who captures the open command from the builtins module. However, since we don't know how many files will be opened, we can use ExitStack. Thus, you can use a function that keeps the file handle within the ExitStack context.

My version for that is:

```
def close_opened_files(func):
@functools.wraps(func)
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    import builtins
    _open = getattr(builtins, 'open')
    try:
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            def myopen(*args, **kwargs):
                f = stack.enter_context(_open(*args, **kwargs))
                return f
            setattr(builtins, 'open', myopen)
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return ret
    finally:
        setattr(builtins, 'open', _open)
return wrapper
```

At the end of the decorator, the original open function should be restored in the builtins module.

One of the problems with this type of approach is: the functions that are called inside `func` and that use the `open` function, will also have their files closed at the end of decorator, even if it represents an error.

Here are some examples:

The following examples show read and write operations, also with files being closed within the function.

```
@close_opened_files
def test_write(fn1, fn2=None):
    f1 = open(fn1, 'w')
    print('Hello world', file=f1)
    if fn2:
        f2 = open(fn2, 'w')
        print('foo-bar', file=f2)
        f2.close()

@close_opened_files
def test_read(fn1, fn2=None):
    f1 = open(fn1, 'r')
    for line in f1: print(line)
    if fn2:
        f2 = open(fn2, 'r')
        for line in f2: print(line)
        f2.close()

test_write('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')
test_read('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')

try: test_read('non_exist_filename.txt')
except FileNotFoundError as ex: print(ex)

try: test_exception('file1.txt')
except RuntimeError as ex: print(ex)
```

These last examples show the decorator under the exceptions: 'no file exists', or any other exception that happens.
The last case, file will be closed before the exception is raised.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it would be possible to use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html) to traverse the code for file openings, and attempt to close any files that were found to have been opened.

Comment: Ok, so how would one implement that?